# passing a seed through different boost random number generator

Tags: c++, boost, random, stringstream

I am passing a streamstring from one random generator to another to keep track of the current state of an engine (boost random library). It allows me stop at any point and save the current state to reproduce a series later on in the code or continue it.

It works fine until I use different random generators while passing the same stringstream (as reproduce bellow). I cannot use different streams for the two, as in the real example a class will call to different distributions in a random order...

```
#ifndef RANDOM_HPP
#define RANDOM_HPP
namespace RandomG{

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::random; 


int getSeed()
{
   ifstream rand("/dev/urandom");
   char tmp[sizeof(int)];
   rand.read(tmp,sizeof(int));                                                          
   rand.close();
   int* number = reinterpret_cast<int*>(tmp);                                           
   return (*number);                                                                    
}
void Get_Rstream(stringstream &s)
{               
     mt19937 randgen(getSeed());                                                      
     s.clear();
     s << randgen;                                                                    
}                                                                                        

template<class distribution>                                                             
class Random                                                                             
{                                                                                        
    public:                                                                          
       Random(distribution nd)                                                         
       {       
              mt19937 randgen(getSeed());                                              
              rng=new variate_generator<mt19937,distribution >(randgen, nd);           
       }       
       virtual ~Random()
       {       
              delete rng;                                                              
       }               
       void reset(void)
       {
             (*rng).distribution().reset();                                           
       }       
       double operator()(stringstream &s)                                               
       {                                                                                
             double x;
             s >> (*rng).engine();
             x=(*rng)();
            return x;
       }
    variate_generator<mt19937,distribution > *rng;
};

}
#endif
```

So now if I instantiate two instances of these classes (below its two uniform but it could be a uniform and a Gaussian or anything else and could be called in a random order).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp>                                          
#include <boost/random/variate_generator.hpp>
#include "Random.hpp"                                                                    
using namespace boost::random;                                                           
using namespace std;                                                                     



int main()  
{        

            int M=20;
            stringstream ss;
            RandomG::Get_Rstream(ss);
            string ss2=ss.str();
            stringstream ss3;
            ss3.clear();                                                             
            ss3.str(ss.str());

            boost::random::uniform_01<> N;
            RandomG::Random<boost::random::uniform_01<> > *unif_rand1= new    RandomG::Random<boost::random::uniform_01<> >(N);
            boost::random::uniform_01<> U;
            RandomG::Random<boost::random::uniform_01<> > *unif_rand2=new RandomG::Random<boost::random::uniform_01<> >(U);

            (*unif_rand1).reset();
            (*unif_rand2).reset();
            for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
            {       
                    cout << (*unif_rand1)(ss) << " ";
            }
            for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
            {
                    cout << (*unif_rand2)(ss) << " ";
            }
            cout <<"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"<<"\n";
            (*unif_rand1).reset();
            (*unif_rand2).reset();
            for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
            {
                    cout << (*unif_rand1)(ss3) << " ";
            }
            for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
            {
                    cout << (*unif_rand2)(ss3) << " ";
            }

return 0;
}
```

This should give me two series of the same random numbers,  but instead gives me the same random numbers for `unif_rand1` but not for `unif_rand2`.
From what I understood feeding the same state to two different random number generator should give the same result or is there some way to reset them between draws ?

results:

```
0.525384 0.038626 0.563798 0.705042 0.725001 0.311586 0.843047 0.606338 0.163695 0.437574 \\\\\\\\\\
0.525384 0.038626 0.563798 0.705042 0.725001 0.0566288 0.93966 0.417343 0.686245 0.84118
```

Thanks for any responses or advises
(the code should be reproducible under linux).

Comment: Are you asking why uniform and normal distributions give different random numbers?

Comment: nope, I am asking why if I alternate between two instances a classe with different engines for which I stream the same state I get different values... The above examples gives different sequences (and they are both uniform with the same stream although with different underlying instances of engines)

Comment: I actually found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638237/boost-random-number-library-use-same-random-number-generator-for-different-vari). (which obviously I had looked for for quite a while and hadn't stumbled upon)

So by passing a unique instantiation of the mt19937 class by reference in every of my random generator class I manage to have the correct behavior (`variate_generator<mt19937 &,distribution >`).

I still don't understand however why I had the first strange behavior as a RNG is supposed to be deterministic with respect to its state...

Comment: You are seeding the generator from /dev/urandom - which would be different each time.

Comment: Yes I agree that the engine is set randomly at first in the constructor, but it is then change in the code. So that both engine shoud be equal `ss3.str(ss.str())`. Proof is, the modification in the above comment did change the behavior.